# Fluid width of input text side by submit

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am try to create a search field with a submit button, where the submit button width is based on it's content, and I try to make the input field width to be fluid, and as max as possible. It's in jQuery mobile.

I've found [this solution](https://boulderinformationservices.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/input-field-and-submit-button-on-the-same-line-full-width/), and tried to implement it without success. Here is a test [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5xwb2rr2/2/)

I've tried it on a simple html page, and on that it works.

Can somebody point me to where am I made the mistake?

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="main"  class="ui-content">
    <form method="post">
        <div class="searchContainer">

            <input type="submit" name="search" value="Go" style="float: right" />
            <div style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: .5em;">
                <input type="text" name="term" style="width: 100%;" />
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="op" value="search" />
        </div>
    </form>

    Here comes the content
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want? The submit button to only be as wide as the word 'go'?

Comment: Yes, and float right to the input, and if I resize the screen, input should strech.

Comment: Add your css sheet to the fiddle

Comment: No css. There is the inline css, as you see. It's a simple jQuery mobile, what is in the fiddle. If you put that content of searchContainer in an empty HTML, that works.

Comment: Jquery Mobile put divs around the elements with this classes - ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow

Comment: Yes, I know, I could inspect elements. I've tried to turn off the css rules, without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this CSS in your code

```
.searchContainer > div:first-child {float:right;display:inline-block;}
```

button will get arranged as per the content.

This is generic solution. You can write it using class name.

Comment: It's seems ok, I try to implement it.

Comment: Thank you, it's working great. But, can just explain me, why does it not works, if I added these rules directly in inline style on the button?

Comment: As you are using jQuery Mobile, it's adding one parent container to the search area, due to which inline style are not working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using table will do the job

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel">
            <h2>Panel Header..</h2>

        <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
         <h1>header</h1>

    </div>
    <!-- /header -->
<div data-role="main"  class="ui-content">
            <form method="post">
                <div class="searchContainer">
                <table style="width: 100%;">    
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="term" style="width: 100%;" /></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="search" value="Go" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>


                    <input type="hidden" name="op" value="search" />
                </div>
            </form>

            Here comes the content
        </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
            <h1>Copyright © </h1>

    </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/5xwb2rr2/3/)**

Comment: Oh no, no way using table for this in 2014... Table is for table data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want side by side elements without width, remove float and set `display:inline-block;` to both elements. Or if button have fixed width (eg 70px), use float with `calc()` for input field width. `width: calc(100% - 70px)`

Comment: I've tried it. If I just use inline block, then text input won't be streched.